# How to create reports that has a cut off period in Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, reporting, report

I am new in creating applications using Visual Studio 2010. I am currently creating a Allowance Report where the user can input all the allowances of a certain person. A person has a fixed allowance for a certain period of time. My problem now is how can I specify that this certain person has a fixed amount of $500.00 per cut off period? I already created a form that I can input all different cut off period and save  the data into my database(MS Access 2007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a table that stores the information:

```
CutOffAmounts:
    CutOffId
    PersonId
    PeriodBeginDate
    PeriodEndDate
    CutOffAmount
```

With the example you gave:

```
Row 1:
    CutOffId = 1
    PersonId = 1
    CutOffAmount = 500.00
    PeriodBeginDate = 11/1/2011
    PeriodEndDate = 11/30/2011
```

Then in your code, validate that the information entered matches up with the constraints in the database eg. the amount is <= 500.00 and the period falls within the PeriodBeginDate and PeriodEndDate range.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but where can I specify the date of each cut off period?